# Creating a "Stream Order" of canal system using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, stream-order, water

I'm interested in creating a "Stream Order" for our canal system. I am the GIS Specialist for an irrigation district. I would like to have the ability to have a layer for when I click on a section of canal, it traces/highlights upstream all the way to our source of surface water. All of our water comes from the same source to the east, and disperses among hundreds of miles of canal to cover our district.

What tool would I use to do that in ArcMap?

Comment: You may want to look into geometric networks, or utility networks.  These will allow you to do network tracing.  But first, you'd have to create the network, which defines not only the components in the network, but how they relate to each other, and the rules governing flow, etc.

Comment: Check out the Trace Geometric Network tool.  This requires a lot of initial set up (of the geometric network) before you can start using the tool.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/trace-geometric-network.htm

Comment: Rivex (rivex.co.uk) is an extremely useful Arc extension that I've used many times (no association to the Rivex developer) for stream network identification and analysis, in including stream order.  Powerful and complete.